# Сегментация клеток с помощью opencv

Tags: python, opencv

Здравствуйте. Есть вот такая картинка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Необходимо определить область каждой клетки, отделить ее от соседней, обвести контуром. Некоторые клетки находятся в процессе деления, их необходимо выделить особенно (другим цветом).
Также надо посчитать количество клеток. Каждая клетка должна превратится в некий объект для дальнейшего анализа. Вот такая задача сигментации.
Пытаюсь решать ее с помощью **opencv** и **python**. В opencv я совсем новичок, поэтому для начала попробовал алгоритм из документации для сегментации монет: https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html

Но для моей картинки это не подходит, контуры плохо выделяются, получается каша. 
Видимо это из-за того что внутренности клетки примерно одно цвета с фоном. Пробовал играться с параметрами, но безуспешно. Добился вот такой картинки: [image: введите сюда описание изображения] на этом и застрял. Сомневаюсь что я двигаюсь в правильном направлении.
Мой вопрос: Какой алгоритм подошел бы мне? С чего начинать? Что почитать на этот счет? Заранее благодарю.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Finding number of colored shapes from picture using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5298884/4279)